# URL of server.php/123 still received by server.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

So I have been fiddling around with `backbone.js` today and was thinking about how to get my PHP code to work with AJAX requests that look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "server.php/123",
    data : "empty string",
    type : "POST" // or "GET" - interested in both
});
```

Just messing around, I discovered that if the above URL is sent, then "server.php" still receives the request. I was very surprised to see this, as I expected to need to do some sort of `mod_rewrite` nonsense to get this to work.

Based upon this discovery, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this common to most/all servers? I'm running a WAMP localhost with Zend.
2. Is it possible, in `server.php`, to access the information that is sent after the "/" without doing mod_rewrite stuff (e.g., with a call of "server.php/123" I want to access the "123" from server.php). I realize that, in backbone's case, it sends the information as part of the JSON, so this is just me trying to learn about how PHP works.

Comment: `server.php?123` is very different from `server.php/123`, as the latter doesn't have provide any information at all in the `$_GET` var, so that comment doesn't really apply.

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is empty in this instance

Comment: Yeah, just realised that, try `PATH_INFO` instead. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php): `Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string, if available.`

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the winner. I've added an answer to comprehensively demonstrate this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the responders. To provide a comprehensive answer, let's say this is your call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/server.php/123/456",
    data : "some string",
    type : "GET"
});
```

Here are the results of various `$_SERVER` vars:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = "/server.php/123/456"
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = "/123/456"
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/server.php/123/456?data=some+string"
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = "data=some+string"
```

Alternatively, if you did:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/server.php/123/456",
    data : "some string",
    type : "POST"
});
```

Then the values returned are identical except for "?data=some+string" is not in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is empty, so no surprises there.

Accordingly, as @Yoshi suggested above, the winner seems to be `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. Indeed, this should not be surprising either, as I seem to have missed this in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) on `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`:

> "Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual
>   script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For
>   instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL
>   http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then
>   $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would contain /some/stuff."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is common, and yes you can access it:

```
$url_parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($url_parts);
```